# Why do scrollbars disappear in tabbed iFrames in Chrome

Tags: jquery, iframe, scrollbar

Got an iFrame in a tabbed container, with vertical and horizontal scrollbars on the iFrame. All is fine until I switch to the other tab, then back again to the first tab.  Suddenly the scrollbars have disappeared!  Using the fiddle this only seems to happen in Chrome, while Firefox and IE seem OK (all recent versions).  I've already got scroll commands in CSS AND on the iFrame code. Anyone any ideas what I can do to fix this?  Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5163yg4d/

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css



    <div id="My_RH_BigContainer">
  <div id="RH_tabsContainer">

    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-img" style="display: block;">
        <label>Table 1</label>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar-img">
        <label>Table 2</label>
      </div>

      <ul id="RH_TabsTable" class="nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href='#Tabular1a_ws' rel="nofollow">Table 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#myblank" rel="nofollow">Table 2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="TabContentID" class="tab-content">
      <div id="Tabular1a_ws" class="tab_pane">

        <iframe name="New_country_TABULAR" id="New_country_TABULAR" scrolling="yes" src="https://c2amf323.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=3eb8400026cba1edcbdb4b28b774">Sorry, but your browser does not support frames.</iframe>
      </div>

      <div id="myblank" class="tab_pane">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>





#New_country_TABULAR {
height: 200px;
overflow: scroll !important;
border: 1px solid #000 !important;
width: 100%;
}

#My_RH_BigContainer {
position: absolute;
height: 360px;
border: 1px solid red;
top: 20px;
left: 15px;
width: 360px;
}

#RH_tabsContainer {
Margin-top: 15px;
Margin-bottom: 5px;
Margin-left: 15px;
Margin-right: 15px;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 330px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}

.sidebar-img {
display: none;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 40px;
background-color: lightgrey;
border: 0px solid black;
}

.nav-tabs {
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
background: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
float: left;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
margin-right: 0px;
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
background-image: none;
outline-color: transparent;
border: 0px solid grey;
line-height: 16px;
font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
height: 20px;
width: 115px;
}

.ui-tabs-active {
border-style: solid;
border-color: black !important;
border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
}

.ui-tabs-active a {
color: red !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
background: white;
color: black;
}

#RH_TabsTable {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}




    $(function() {

  var index = 'qpsstats-active-tab';
  var dataStore = sessionStorage;
  var oldIndex = 0;
  try {
    // getter: Fetch previous value
    oldIndex = dataStore.getItem(index);
  } catch (e) {}

  $("#RH_tabsContainer").tabs({

    active: oldIndex,

    activate: function(event, ui) {
      //  Get future value
      var newIndex = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
      //  Set future value
      try {
        dataStore.setItem(index, newIndex);
     } catch (e) {}

      $('.sidebar-img').hide();
      $('.sidebar-img').eq(ui.newTab.index()).show();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Wow, I think I've managed to answer my own question and this marks the first time I've been able to give something back to SO instead of just taking.  I discovered that zooming back and forth and using a small delay brings the scrollbars back.  See updated fiddle with addition jquery function at the end. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8y9rqtps/

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Our solution was to reload the iFrame via js by each tab change.

But nice to see an other workaround. Thanks!